# How to get input array values

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with multiple input array id's

for example:

```
    <div>
        <input name='set1[]'>
        <input name='set2[]'>
        <input name='set3[]'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name='set1[]'>
        <input name='set2[]'>
        <input name='set3[]'>
    </div>
```

The problem I have is if I leave out one of my sets my array key position is '0' instead of '1'. Use below as an example:

```
    <div>
        <input name='set1[]'>
        <input name='set2[]'>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name='set1[]'>
        <input name='set2[]'>
        <input name='set3[]'>
    </div>
```

When set 3 isn't in the first div, set 3 key value is '0' when I need it to be '1'.

I am using Jquery to append each 'set'. Any ideas on how to get the 'set3[]' to be key value '1'?

here is my Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var max_fields = 9; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap_ex1"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button_ex1"); //Add button 
 
    $(document).on("click", ".add_field_button_ex1", function (e) { //on add input button click 
    var num = $(this).parents().children('.setsdiv').length;
    var index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings().children().index('#myinputwkout');
    alert(index);
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).parents().children('.setsdiv').length < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            $container=$(this).parent().parent().parent();
            $container.append('<div id="setsdiv" class="col-xs-12 text-center setsdiv"><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 nopad"><input id="set" class="form-control input-sm setinput text-center col-xs-6 set" type="text" name="sets'+ num +'[]" placeholder="Weight" pattern="\\d*"></div><div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 nopad"><input id="reps" class="form-control input-sm setinput text-center col-xs-6 reps" type="text" name="reps'+ num +'[]" placeholder="Reps" pattern="\\d*"></div><div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><a class="btn btn-xs btn-default remove_field pull-right">Remove</a><a class="same btn btn-xs btn-default" href="#">Same</a></div></div>'); //add input box
            $container.find('.set:last').focus();

}
});

    $(document).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.setsdiv').remove();
    })

    $(document).on("click", ".same", function (e) { //user click on same text
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get
    var set = $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('#set').val();
    var rep = $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('#reps').val();

        //Set
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('#set').val(set);
    $(this).parent().siblings().children('#reps').val(rep);

    })

});
```

Comment: Post you jquery please

Comment: ??? array key start from `0` not `1` unless you set it

Comment: Added my Jquery. Yes, I know it starts at 0. I need set3[] in the first div to actually be placed into my array with value '0'. When set3[] in the fist div isn't on the page, set3[] in my second div becomes key value '0'. This is not what I need. I need set3[] in div 2 to ALWAYS be key value '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I added to my Jquery....

```
        var index = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().prevAll('.form-group').length;
var index = index - 1;
```

Then I put into my 'append()'

```
    sets'+ num +'[' + index + ']
```

This did the trick!